# How to play and pause animation

Tags: unity, c#

I want to make play and pause buttons to play and pause sound and also I want it to play and pause animation ,how should I do that?

```
//function 
 public void TogglePlay()
    {
        if (audio.isPlaying)
        {
            audio.Pause();
        }
        else
        {
            audio.Play();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Animator has a [speed property.](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator-speed.html) If you set it to 0, it will stop playing. Then set it back to 1 to resume playback.

```
public void TogglePlay()
{
    if (audio.isPlaying)
    {
        audio.Pause();
        animator.speed = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        audio.Play() ;
        animator.speed = 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use an [AudioSource](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-AudioSource.html), because this can change between multiple [AudioClip](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-AudioClip.html), which is a specific sound, so you can play multiple sounds.

You'll have to attach all needed components in editor before this.

1. An AudioSource component to your AudioSource field and drag the AudioClip into that AudioSource Component.
2. A Button component on the btnMusic field.
3. An Animator on the animator field and create an animation in the Animator tab in the editor.

Then in your GameManager you can do something like this:

```
public AudioSource audioSource;
public Animator animator;
public Button btnMusic;

void Start()
{
    audioSource.Play("name-of-your-audio-clip");
    btnMusic.onClick.AddListener(BtnMusicOnClick);
}

void BtnMusicOnClick(){
    if (audioSource.isPlaying) {
        audioSource.Pause();
    } else {
        audioSource.UnPause();
    }
    animator.Play("btnMusicOnClick");
}
```

Comment: I use animator not animation

Comment: @Sh.Adel it works the same, I've updated the example. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: this play animation how to pause it if sound paused?(pause animation not stop it)